# Extension method on generic type, with additional generic type parameters

Tags: generics, extension-methods, type-inference

I would like to write an extension method for a generic type, with additional generic type parameters.  I have working code already, but don't like the result, because the user is required to re-enter the generic type parameters of the existing type.

I have a concrete example, but keep in mind that this is a general problem.  I appreciate feedback on the particular problem at hand, but I am looking for general solutions.

For a class of type `Action<T>`, add an extension method with a signature similar to this:

```
Func<T, TResult> ToFunc<TResult>();
```

Here's my working code:

```
public static class DelegateExtensions
{
  public static Func<T, TResult> ToFunc<T, TResult>(this Action<T> action)
  {
    return arg => { action(arg); return default(TResult); };
  }
}
```

But the usage stinks:

```
public void TakesAFunc(Func<int, float> someFunc) { /* ... */ }
// ...
Action<int> someIntAction = /* ... */;
TakesAFunc(someIntAction.ToFunc<int, float>());
```

In this example, the `int` generic parameter is the only value that is acceptable, so it causes unnecessary code duplication.

Type inference does not work here.  I think this is because you can't infer a generic parameter via return type.

This code would solve the problem, but unfortunately does not seem to work:

```
public static class DelegateExtensions<T>
{
  public static Func<T, TResult> ToFunc<TResult>(this Action<T> action)
  {
    return arg => { action(arg); return default(TResult); };
  }
}
```

Usage would be exactly like you'd expect:

```
public void TakesAFunc(Func<int, float> someFunc) { /* ... */ }
// ...
Action<int> someIntAction = /* ... */;
TakesAFunc(someIntAction.ToFunc<float>());
```

I noticed that `System.Linq.Queryable` works the way my first chunk of code does, though it usually doesn't need extra type parameters, so type inference works.

Is there any known trick to get around requiring these duplicate generic type parameters?  One thought that comes to mind would be code generators or macros of some sort, but I can't think of how I'd do it cleanly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One common trick for this sort of thing is to pass a dummy value of the desired type just for type inference, which is required in certain scenarios involving anonymous types.

```
public static class DelegateExtensions
{
  public static Func<T, TResult> 
  ToFunc<T, TResult>(this Action<T> action, TResult ignored)
  {
    return arg => { action(arg); return default(TResult); };
  }
}
```

How good of a trick this is is up to personal opinion, but this would confuse me every time I called it and every time I came back to a place that I called it.  You could also change the semantics of the method to make the second parameter be the return value, allowing the caller to decide if they want the default value or not.

As to your second example, I'm pretty sure extension methods are not allowed on generic types, but I don't have a link handy

Comment: "You could also change the semantics of the method to make the second parameter be the return value".  Good catch :)  I am doing this in my code, but simplified it for my sample code.  I was providing a default value for it, so wasn't getting inference - maybe I'll make it a required parameter.  "I'm pretty sure extension methods are not allowed on generic types" - yep, that's why it won't work.  Maybe it'd be confusing for users, but it'd be nice for cases like this for C#/the framework to add such support.

Comment: "which is required in certain scenarios involving anonymous types" - piques my curiosity a bit.  Can you provide a link/example in the framework?

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham: I don't know of anywhere that they have a parameter like that in the framework.  One function you can't use with an anonymous type because of that is Enumerable.Empty.  If you wanted `var results = (condition) ? /*anonymous type query*/ : Enumerable.Empty</*what to put here*/>();`, you couldn't.  Really though, the scenarios are rare and can generally be worked around.  Your function would be one example where this would also be required if `TResult` was to be an anonymous type.

Answer (score 2):

I am late to the party - sorry.

As has been mentioned - this is not currently possible with out switching the *Func* to an out param.

I'll throw out another way to do this sort of thing - it gets to look a bit fluid syntax like, but it works.

```
 public class ActionWrap<T>
{
    private readonly Action<T> _action;

    internal ActionWrap(Action<T> action)
    {
        _action = action;
    }

    public Func<T, TResult> OfType<TResult>()
    {
        return arg => { _action(arg); return default(TResult); };
    }
}

public static class DelegateExtensions
{
    public static ActionWrap<T> ToFunc<T>(this Action<T> action)
    {
        return new ActionWrap<T>(action);
    }
}
```

Then calling it goes:

```
Action<int> x = z=> Console.WriteLine(z);
Func<int, float> asFunc = x.ToFunc().OfType<float>();
```

This is not exactly what you wanted, but it achieves the goal of not stating the int generic again and can be extended to other cases where you want to do something similar.